# jQuery: Selector confusion

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What is wrong with this jQuery selector?

```
$("#masterHeaderMenu.masterHeaderMenuButton a:first")
```

I'm intending to select the first anchor tag that is a child of an element whose class is "`masterHeaderMenuButton`", itself a child of the element with an "`id`" attribute value of "`masterHeaderMenu`".

Can't I do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 6):

You need an extra space in there, like this:

```
$("#masterHeaderMenu .masterHeaderMenuButton a:first")
```

Without the space, `#masterHeaderMenu.masterHeaderMenuButton` is looking for an element that has `id="masterHeaderMeny"` **and** `class="masterHeaderMenuButton"`, with the space, it's saying find `class="masterHeaderMenuButton"` that's a descendant of the `#masterHeaderMeny`, not the same element.

If you want to go down any number of levels, add a space, if you want to go down **only** a level, use `>`, this means only go down to immediate children.

Answer (score 4):

You can. You need a space between the first element (ID) and the second (class):

```
$("#masterHeaderMenu .masterHeaderMenuButton a:first")
```

Your selector looked for an element that had the ID "masterHeaderMenu" *and* CSS class "masterHeaderMenuButton".

Answer (score 0):

**There is no need of specifying class**. if you give the ID name in the selector itself is enough.
***An ID can represent single html element in the document. but the class can represent a group of html elements.***

```
$("#masterHeaderMenu .masterHeaderMenuButton a:first")
```

this selector may take time.
the same result can be get from this code `$("#masterHeaderMenu a:first")`

Comment: This is incorrect, if he has 20 elements beneath `#masterHeaderMenu` with links your "same result" answer will get the first link from all of them, not the first link from the one with that class, they are **not** the same.

Comment: I was wrong! I thought that he intending to select the first anchor tag which is a child of an element whose class is "masterHeaderMenuButton", and it has id "masterHeaderMenu".